# Decode JWT token in Php from node server

Tags: php

i need help using jwt lib in php to decode a jwt token that i get in php backend.
the code on the front is like this:

`axios.post('http://localhost:3000/getUser').then(res=>console.log(res)`

now in the backend i do receive the token but how can I decode it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi You can simply do :

`$data = $request->data;`

`$decoded = JWT::decode($data->token, $key, array('HS256'));`

where $key is the secret used to encode the data.